# Quadratic Approximation

Tags: calculus

Find the quadratic approximation of:

$$sec(t) \over \sqrt{1-t^2}$$

for  $ t \approx 0$

I am aware of the general formula for quadratic approximation, but isn't there a way to rearrange this so that I can take approximation of basic functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we go via the direct differentiation route, we need $f(0)$, $f'(0)$, and $f''(0)$. Not too bad, but the second derivative is somewhat unpleasant to calculate.

We can alternately find the quadratic approximations of $\sec t$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$, and multiply.

Or else (recycling is a good thing) we can note that $\cos t\approx 1-t^2/2$ and $\sqrt{1-t^2}\approx 1-t^2/2$. Thus $(\cos t)\sqrt{1-t^2}\approx 1-t^2$, and therefore its reciprocal is $\approx 1+t^2$.